# IBM Watson text-to-speech curl example not working

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

Here is the command I am using to test the text-to-speech API:

```
/usr/bin/curl -k -u 'USERNAME':'PASSWORD' -X POST \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Accept: audio/wav' \
  --data '{"text":"hellow world","voice":"en-US_AllisonVoice"}' \
  'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize' > ./public/138106.wav
```

The command above doesn't seem to generate the desired audio file. I have a bluemix account and the right credentials. An audio file is generated, but it's corrupt.

Comment: sorry the question got cut off! the above command i am using doesn't seem to generate the desire audo file. i have a bluemix account and the right credentials. a audio file is generated but its corrupt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`voice` is a URL parameter. The correct curl command looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/curl -k -u 'USERNAME':'PASSWORD' -X POST \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Accept: audio/wav' \
  --data '{"text":"hellow world"}' \
  'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_AllisonVoice'
```

Disclosure: I am an evangelist for IBM Watson.

Comment: This .wav file does not play on IOS . And since I am building an IOS app with text 2 speech its not a solution. Any ideas on the format for IOS ?

Answer (score 1):

`--data '{"text":"hellow world","voice":"en-US_AllisonVoice"}'`

Try this:

`--data "{\"text\":\"hello world\", \"voice\":\"en-US_AllisonVoice\"}"`

I took this syntax from the API documentation found here: https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/quick-curl.shtml

It seems they have built the syntax of the JSON differently than your command.

Comment: Hm, try what @Leo said below, take out the whole voice:en-US... part of the JSON, and follow the documentation for the API

Comment: actually I've deleted my answer (because it's a workaround, not a real solution) and I've opened a ticket internally at bluemix asking for a real example in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it not using the cURL scripting recommendation.
But by going directly to the url: https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize

Then removing the following 2 lines:

- `"word_alternatives_threshold": null,`
- `"keywords_threshold": null,`

There are issues with these lines.